# If magnetic fields do not have any energy in them then, how could they work on charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

We know that a magnetic field which is changing and is perpendicular to the velocity of charge $q1$ will create an Electric field which acts upon that $q1$ and does some work. Here the work is being done by an electric field which was created by a change in the magnetic field.

I have read that magnetic fields do not contain any energy in them. If they do not contain any energy, then how is the energy being transferred from the magnetic field to $q1$.

Changing magnetic field explains the amount energy released but it doesn't explain who is bringing that energy to $q1$.

My point: Magnetic fields cannot bring this energy to $q1$ since they don't contain any energy !!!

Can anyone explain it if he/she knows about it very well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_energy

Comment: "I have read that Magnetic fields do not contain any energy in them." You have been misled. The energy per unit volume of a magnetic field in empty space is $$u=\frac {1}{2\mu_0}B^ 2$$in which $B$ is the magnitude of the magnetic flux density.

Answer (score 3):

> I have read that Magnetic fields do not contain any energy in them

This is incorrect. Either you have misunderstood a correct source or you have read an incorrect source.

The energy density term of Poynting’s theorem is given by $$U= \frac{1}{2} \left( \epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0} B^2 \right)$$

So there is indeed a positive energy density when $E=0$ and $B\ne 0$

Comment: "Some people are saying that magentic fields have energy in them." I know what to do now. I want to ask you-- Why the magentic energy gained by different velocity gaining test charges is different. Means that Source charge is same and it doesn't release any extra energy for any special test charge. So, how do different charges are capable of getting different amount of force from that single source charge. It seems like if a charge were moving at a velocity of 200,000km/sec then, it would have absorbed a lot more energy  than a test charge moving with 1m/s velocity near source charge

Comment: It seems like if you are right then, a source charge would have relelased infinite energy in that magnetic field lines since the force is dependent on velocity of test charge which can change. At least the equations are saying so. Or the minimum energy required in field is the energy that we can take out from it which is by moving a charge with largest velocity attainable.  But now there are peoples who would say magnetic fields don't do work but i would say," as they are creating electruc fields which are doing work on test charge, we can say that magnetic field is doing work indirectly"

Comment: @ArsenalCreation asked “Can we have a complete discussion about this topic?” This forum is really set up for a straight question and answer approach. It actively discourages discussion. For discussion you might try physicsforums.com where I am also active

Comment: Ok can you answer the above comments cause i am now sick of askinh the same thing again and again and people giving totally different or opposite answers

Comment: @ArsenalCreation I am sorry but your comments are all over the place. I don’t know what you are asking in the comments. It really seems like more than can be done in comments here. However, I would strongly recommend reading about Poynting’s theorem which is the central concept for energy in electromagnetism.